# setLineDash([3,2]), draws a Solid Line instead of dashed lines. (Canvas HTML5)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, rendering

I'm trying to draw different rectangular designs using setLineDash and lineDashOffset(HTML5 Canvas-2d Context). But Solid lines are drawn instead of dashed lines. Please help.

Points to be noted:

1. Canvas Scaling is done.
2. drawLine API is used for drawing lines.
3. I'm using different integer points to draw lines.
4. setLineDash([3,2]). Strictly, dashed thickness is "3" and space between them is "2" should be used.

`

```
this.context.setLineDash([3,2]);
this.context.lineDashOffset = 2;  
drawLine(300,9.5,570,10);
drawLine(300,9.5,300,100);
drawLine(300,99.5,570,100);
drawLine(570,9.5,570,100);`
```

My Complete code for your reference:
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/sathyan/pen/GRNyQqj)

Inspired from:
[Document Link](https://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/html-canvas-setLineDash.php)

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could include `drawLine` in your question, since this was actually where the problem came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you close the path using `closePath()`.

This method doesn't say "the path declaration is over", it says, "make my path an enclosed path", which means it will `lineTo` the last entrance point in the path. Doing so and depending on the line's length, the second line may have its own dashes cover the holes of the first line.

```js
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, mode) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  switch (mode) {
    case "closePath":
      context.closePath();
    case "lineTo":
      context.lineTo(x1, y1);
  }
  context.stroke();
}
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.setLineDash([3, 2]);

context.strokeStyle = "red";
drawLine(30, 9.5, 30, 100, "closePath");
context.strokeStyle = "blue";
drawLine(60, 9.5, 60, 100, "lineTo");
context.strokeStyle = "green";
drawLine(90, 9.5, 90, 100, "");
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

And to avoid this, don't call `closePath()`.